# creating a project: starting from scratch -> JSON/Mongo/Raw code in console?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

~

So I'm trying to embark on creating a project of my very own, on my own, with only the information on the internet (and this wonderful community) available to me.

I am a beginner attempting to solidify my understanding of callbacks/higher order functions/and front-end HTML/CSS.

In order to apply this knowledge (I understand functional programming on a conceptual basis), I want to create my own JSON database from which I can create my own prototype methods and use existing ones (map/reduce/filter).

**Central question:**

How do you go about inputting the data you want? I can't imagine people manually create huge objects within the console...

Is this where I should learn MongoDB? 
Is there a JSON generator where it's easier to input your data?

Note: I know that there are JSON randomizers that will create a JSON database for you to use, but I'd actually like to make the data myself and then operate on it with the javascript console.

Comment: You'd seed the database in some way, manually, or otherwise. I don't think there is a secret to seeding...

Comment: Check out something like Project Gutenberg.  Some sort of online repository where you can download a bunch of data.  Might need to write a script to clean it up and put it in your mongo db.  There's a book called 'Node.js the Right Way' that does this very thing.  And no, I'm not the author and have no association with him.

Comment: okay so going forward I will do the following..

1. learn what seeding is (haha)
2. download a bunch of data from something like Gutenberg
3. MongoDB is essential for having your JS console access the JSON
4. Read about Node.JS

thank you for the tips! :)